# I need to create a pyspark UDF that outputs a table from a query with a comparison

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am working with the IBM attrition data set on Kaggle. What I am trying to do is count occurrences of categorical variables to `Attrition == 'Yes'`, and `Attrition == 'No'`, and take the simple ratio to see which level of the categorical variable is more likely to attrite. Now I can do this in Pandas, like this:

```
def cal_ratio(x):
    n_1 = sum(x['Attrition'].values == 'Yes')
    n_0 = sum(x['Attrition'].values == 'No')
    return n_1/n_0
```

Or I could easily enough write a spark.sql query that does it, and re-write it for each categorical variable I want to compare. A function like this one for Pandas would make my life easier, but I can't find any real guidance on how to create this sort of UDF nor how to register it.

EDIT: may be helpful if I ask also how would this work in pyspark with the UDF?

```
b = data.groupby('BusinessTravel').apply(cal_ratio)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it is the best solution but you can try this :

```py
# My sample dataframe
df.show()
+---------+                                                                     
|Attrition|
+---------+
|      Yes|
|      Yes|
|      Yes|
|      Yes|
|      Yes|
|       No|
|       No|
+---------+
```

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result = (
    df.agg(
        F.sum(F.when(F.col("Attrition") == "Yes", 1)).alias("Yes"),
        F.sum(F.when(F.col("Attrition") == "No", 1)).alias("No"),
    )
    .select((F.col("Yes") / F.col("No")).alias("ratio"))
    .first()
)

print(result.ratio)
> 2.5
```

You can, of course, transform the `result` thing to a function by replacing the hard-coded values with variables.

```py
def cal_ratio(df):
    result = (
        df.agg(
            F.sum(F.when(F.col("Attrition") == "Yes", 1)).alias("Yes"),
            F.sum(F.when(F.col("Attrition") == "No", 1)).alias("No"),
        )
        .select((F.col("Yes") / F.col("No")).alias("ratio"))
        .first()
    )
    return result.ratio
```

---

EDIT : If you need to group by a column, then you need to replace the `first` with a `collect`:

```py
def cal_ratio(df):
    result = (
        df.groupBy("BusinessTravel")
        .agg(
            F.sum(F.when(F.col("Attrition") == "Yes", 1)).alias("Yes"),
            F.sum(F.when(F.col("Attrition") == "No", 1)).alias("No"),
        )
        .select((F.col("Yes") / F.col("No")).alias("ratio"))
        .collect()
    )
    return result
```